# Problem In Cauchy-Peano proof : why $\int_{t_0}^t C|u(s)-v(s)|ds\leq L(t-t_0)\max_{[t_0,t]}|u(s)-v(s)|$?

Tags: real-analysis

Here the page of one of my course (picard existence theorem). In my first remark in red, normaly the constant $L$ depend on the first variable. So why next to my second remark, the constant $L$ can go out the integral ? (since it normally depend on $t$ and thus can't go out the integral).

(If the document is written to small, you can zoom, the quality will be better :))

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $L$ does not depend on $x$. In particular, the author says, "here all $x\in [\xi,\xi+a]$, $y,\bar y\in\mathbf R$ are allowed."

Comment: Thank you very much. I misunderstood the problem (it was really not clear for me).

Comment: But it's anyway strange that the author wasn't more clear (like really says that $L$ is not dependent on $x$)

Comment: Well, the author said it held for all $x$. That's prettttttty clear ;)